# Can i donwload an App from the App Catalog and install it inside another tenant

Tags: development, spfx, spfx-webparts, administration, app-catalog

I have developed a custom SPFx web part and upload it inside a tenant, as follow:-

[image]

now i want to install the same App inside another tenant, so can i simply download the above sppkg App and install it inside another tenant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can download the package and upload it/install it to a different tenant.